# Why the switch statement displays default in this C calculator?

Tags: c

When I run this program, it ignores everything in the `switch` statement, and displays the `default`. 
I am using Code::Blocks. 
Please explain to me why this logic error is encountered and maybe it is an error in Code::Blocks and not from the code — should I try it on another IDE?

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        double a,b;
        int choose,subtract,divide;
        printf("My first Calculater in c\n");
        printf("\n");
        printf("Enter your two numbers\n");
        scanf("%lf",&a);
        scanf("%lf",&b);
        printf("Please choose an operation\n");
         printf("1.add two no.(s)\n");
         printf("2.subtract two no.(s)\n");
         printf("3.multiply two no.(s)\n");
         printf("4.divide two no.(s)\n");
         printf("please choose an operation ");
           scanf("%lf", &choose);

    switch(choose){

     case 1:
        printf("sum of a+b is : %lf\n",(a+b));
        break;

     case 2:
        printf("1.a-b?\n");
        printf("2.b-a?\n");
        scanf("%d", &subtract);
        switch(subtract)
        {
         case 1:
            printf("\ndiff of a-b is : %lf",(a-b));
            break;

         case 2:
            printf("\ndiff of b-a is : %lf",(b-a));
             break;

        }
     case 3:
            printf("\nproduct of a*b is : %lf",(a*b));
             break;

     case 4:
            printf("\n1.divide a/b?,a!=0");
            printf("\n2.divide b/a?,b!=0");
            scanf("%d", &divide);
            switch(divide)
            {
            case 1:
                if(b==0)
                    printf("\ndivision by zero is undefined");
                    else
                       printf("\nquotient of a/b is : %lf",(a/b));
                    break;
            case 2:

                if(a==0)
                    printf("\ndivision by zero is undefined");
                    else
                        printf("\nquotient of b/a is : %lf",(b/a));
                        break;
           }
     default:
          printf("please choose either 1,2,3 or 4 options\n");
        }

    }
```

Comment: check the field spec in the scan statement.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  Do not tag C questions with the C++ tag.  Do indent your code more meaningfully (avoid tabs when creating code to be displayed in SO).  Assume that your compiler and IDE are perfect — you're unlikely to have found a bug in either, and thinking that it might not be a fault in your code shows that you are a tyro.  It's always your fault — even if you've been programming 30 years.

Comment: One basic debugging technique: print values that are read after you've read them.  You have `scanf("%lf", &choose);`.  You should check that it succeeded, and you should review the type that `"%lf"` looks for and the type that `choose` has.  If your compiler did not tell you about the problem, turn up the warnings or get a better compiler.  (You should also check the other uses of `scanf()` — if you don't get `1` returned each time, you've got input problems, such as a letter instead of a number in the input.)

Comment: It's never Lupus. It's always scanf().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading in a double for `choose`

```
scanf("%lf", &choose);
```

Change to reading a decimal

```
scanf("%d", &choose);
```